# State saving, navigation controller stack saving and gesture recognizer on the navigation bar

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, state-saving

I'm loading my view controllers like this:

```
NSArray *viewControllerNames = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:path];
    for (NSString *viewControllerClass in viewControllerNames) {

        NSString *filePath = [self filePathForClass:NSClassFromString(viewControllerClass)];
        if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePath]) {
            id viewController = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath]];

            [self pushViewController:viewController animated:NO];
        }
    }
```

On my stack's root view controller I am adding a gesture recognizer in the navbar.

However if I pushed some view controller on top it won't load this gesture, because the root view controller's `viewDidLoad` doesn't get called, and if I access the `viewControllers` property of `UINavigationController` it returns nil.

Any ideas how to proceed with this gesture? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using `setViewControllers:animated:` instead of pushing single view controller one by one?

```
NSMutableArray * viewControllers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for(...) { // the same for loop you have 
    ...
    [viewControllers addObject:viewController];
}
[self setViewControllers:viewControllers animated:YES];
```

Comment: There is no such selector for UINavigationController.

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo. It should be `setViewControllers:animated:` instead of `addViewControllers:animated:`.